# how to get final each loops number in JQuery

Tags: jquery, count, numbers, each, final

I've a simple each loop and I want count loops of this while,and find The final number then save counter variable and use in my codes, how can do posible...??!

```
var counter = 0;

$.each(data, function( key, value) {
  counter++;
     if(counter == /*The final number*/)
     {
        //Do Some Codes
     }


})
```

Comment: Just use a counter. Your code is just right.

Comment: when counter would last?? where is loop ????

Comment: If you want number of iteration you can get it by using data.length

Comment: i want do an event just when each loop is on the final loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count loop like this

`.each(function (i) {
}`

here i will give you counter value

Comment: please describe your codes, i don't understand very well

Comment: You want to count your loop here i will give you counter value and in side that you can set whatever logic you want, have you tried this?

Comment: and if you want to do any thing in your last loop then compare value of i with your data.length.